# Trigger - create folder/folder structure on new row

Tags: postgresql, triggers, directory

Hi is there any way to create a folder or folder structure to a specific location on a network drive with postgresql trigger, when a new row added?.

the new row would contains the new folder names in different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for that is to use the (untrusted) procedure language `pl/perlu` for your trigger, where you can use standard perl commandos for filesystem manipulation. You will have to take care about correct access rights for creating the directories, however.

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;

CREATE FUNCTION perlfunc(text) RETURNS integer AS $$
      mkdir($_[0]);
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu
```

Note that the standard `pl/perl`, as a trusted language, will catch such attempts and reject access to the system environment, so indeed plperlu must be used.